# Big icon in chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

[image: chrome webstore search]

I try to make big icon in chrome webstore, but this offer just 128x128, on photo bellow you can see `big icon` and bellow `little icon`, how they make this big icon ?

Comment: that isn't something you set in your extension.  You have to change those in the publishing page.  Look for the promotional images section and set the smallest one to the icon you would like.

Comment: @MarcGuiselin can you please paste bellow tutorial how do this ? because i try all possible and not work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the promotional image, you have to change the 440x280 tile in "promotional tile images" in the chrome extension publishing/editing page. Look for the promotional images section and set the smallest one to the icon you would like.

Click "Upload new image" to set your own preview image.

Click "Preview my promotional tiles" so you can see how the images will look.

You might have to wait until the image is approved, until then it won't display. If your image does not match the criteria (listed [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images?hl=en-US#promo)) for a good display image, it will also not be displayed.  Contact google if nothing works, they just might reply :)

[image: directions]

P.S. That's a nice little game you made there :)  Remove the "tabs" and "suggestqueries.google.com" permissions, your extension doesn't need them, and permissions like that for such a simple extension might scare people.

Answer (score 2):

See [Provide store content](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#provide-store-content), when you publish your app/extension to web store, you would need to provide those images.

> A 128x128 icon to display in the store. You may re-use your app icon here.
>
> At least one 1280x800 or 640x400 screenshot or YouTube video to show off what your app does.
>
> **A 440x280 small tile icon that will be displayed on the Chrome Web Store wall.**

Comment: i add this but still i see just little icon 128x128

Comment: Two weeks have passed after I added it, but it still doesn't show up?